# Is it ok to add data- attribute to the style tag in head?

Tags: html, css

Is it legal to add data- attribute to the style tag in head?

I have found not much on the internet on using attributes with styles in head.
I thought it is more for the body elements.

I am trying to be able to identify different style tags with data-style-id="randomid" for js/jquery easier usage.

Comment: *"I am trying to be able to identify different style tags with data-style-id="randomid" for js/jquery easier usage."* You can also just give them `id`s.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Well, yes, but it would be better to go with data-* because of the functionality I need. I just think it is not necessary to go out of the scope of this question on what exactly I need, therefore, I didnt explain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `data-*` attributes are legal on all HTML elements. From [the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes):

> Every HTML element may have any number of custom data attributes specified, with any value.

As @Alohci notes, there are elements in HTML documents that aren’t HTML elements, though: SVG and MathML elements.

Comment: Do you mean "every" - including even <body>, <head> and <html>? Because when people write "every", some times they may mean every in a particular scope. P. S. I will mark as correct in 8 minutes.

Comment: @Mee: Yes, including all of those. `<title>`, `<col>`, `<meta>`, `<noscript>` too.

Comment: @Ryan - but not `<svg>`, `<math>` etc. which are valid elements of HTML documents, but are not "HTML elements".